# Switch UI Element graphical issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I've implemented a switch ui element to my application. It acts as a music toggle and it works perfectly. however, once you leave the view controller and come back. the switches graphics are set to on but the actual value remains the same as what the user set previously

What could be causing this? and is there any way to fix that, I assume that would be confusing to the user to see the switch as on at all times whether its actually off or not.

@Robotic cat: I don't know what the `prepareForsegue` is...

the `audioPlayer` is set up globally in the main `viewController.swift` file

Relevent code:

```
import UIKit

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBAction func musicToggle(_ sender: UISwitch)
    {
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        if (sender.isOn == true)
        {
            playMusic()
        }
        else if (sender.isOn == false)
        {
            stopMusic()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func playMusic()
    {
        audioPlayer.play()
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    }
    func stopMusic()
    {
        audioPlayer.stop()
    }

}
```

Comment: This sounds like a logic error in your code where you are not setting up the `UISwitch` in the view controller correctly as the view controller loads. To debug this step through your code where you set the state of the `UISwitch` and check the value of your datasource and that the code is setting the correct state.

Comment: I have it set up through a simple IBAction. it simply checks if sender.isOn is true and if it is it plays music if it's false it turns the music off. that's the extent of the switch in my code

Comment: My suggestions are this: `1)` Step through your code (using the debugger and breakpoints) to make sure that the values being set are correct and the logic is correct; it still sounds like a logic issue. `2)` If this does not fix it then post your `prepareForSegue` and all relevant code for the `UISwitch` state so we can review it (you should always do this on SO otherwise the question can be closed for not posting code).

Comment: i've updated my question. I didn't post the code because I was on a different computer, sorry

Comment: would it be better to put `audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()` somewhere else? like in `viewDidAppear` or something of that manner?

Comment: OK. Where are you storing the `UISwitch` state? When you leave the view controller the view controller is deallocated (and the current state of the `UISwitch` is lost). To keep the correct state of the `UISwitch` you need to save it somewhere  when it changes and then set the `UISwitch` to the correct value when the view controller loads. I would also only call `prepareToPlay` when the `UISwitch` toggles to the state corresponding to `play` rather than every time the switch is toggled.

Comment: ok. this is helping a lot, thank you! I'm still very new to iOS development in general. Any tips on how to save the state of the switch? I can always do my own research if you don't feel like being my teacher lol

Comment: Would saving it to user defaults and grabbing that in the `viewDidLoad` do the trick?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131441/discussion-between-chris-levely-and-robotic-cat).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've solved my issue thanks to [Robotic Cat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/558933/robotic-cat)

What I needed to do was save the value of the switch to `UserDefault` and then grab that value in the `viewDidAppear` Function.

This also solved the problem that the music would play no matter what when the app was closed out and re-launched, however, I knew `UserDefaults` was the solution for that.

Comment: +1 for solving this yourself. I'm glad I pointed you in the right direction. I disappeared to have my Christmas Lunch so I'm happy you solved it in the meantime.

Comment: Haha Merry Christmas! I had mine yesterday so the whole family could come. Freeing me up today to get some coding done :)